# Missing semicolon (;) at the end of SQL statement when insert data to ms access table

Tags: database, oracle, ms-access, vb6

this is my code

```
dim straccess as string
Do While Not rso.EOF
30 straccess = "INSERT INTO [test] ([nik],[nama]) VALUES ('" & rso.Fields(0) 
              & "' ,'" & rso.Fields(1) & "' ) where [nama]= '" _
              & rso.Fields(0) & "';"
cna.Execute straccess
Loop
```

got error on line 30 when insert data.

im type this code in vb6 n want to insert data from oracle database/table to msaccess database/table. i already hv connection to oracle table n ms access. And now I try to insert data into MS Access table based data in oracle table

my table name in ms access is TEST and my table name in empmasterepms.

---

this is my all code .

```
Dim vstr As String
Dim filename As String
Dim straccess As String

Option Explicit

Const ORACLEQUERY As String = "select empcode,empname from empmasterepms order by EMPNAME"


Dim cno As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cna As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rso As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsa As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub btnload_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

'-----------------Connection to Oracle
cno.Open "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=192.168.0.15:1521/EPMS;User Id=EPMS_TRXI;Password=epmse292014;"

rso.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rso.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rso.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rso.Open ORACLEQUERY, cno, , , adCmdText
Set dg1.DataSource = rso

------- connect to msaccess
cna.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & vstr

rso.MoveFirst

Do While Not rso.EOF
30 straccess = "Update test SET [nik] = '" & rso.Fields(0).Value & "' ,[nama] = '" & rso.Fields(1).Value & "' WHERE [nama] = '" & rso.Fields(1).Value & "';"

cna.Execute straccess
rso.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Done"
cno.Close
Set cno = Nothing
Set cna = Nothing
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox Erl & ":" & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description

Debug.Print (straccess) 
end sub
```

Comment: where condition in insert statement? r u trying to insert new row or updating an existing riow?

Comment: im trying to updating an existing row. coz i need to change the data in column nama based of column epmsname from my oracle table

Comment: Then you need to use an UPDATE statement, not INSERT.

Comment: if i got primary key in my column nama, is okay right if i use insert method?

Comment: @vinzly if u need to do something in existing row you can only use update. If you need to insert new data insert..In insert no where clause..when u changed this from insert to update does it works?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Where statement:

```
30 straccess = "INSERT INTO [test] ([nik],[nama]) VALUES ('" & rso.Fields(0).Value & "','" & rso.Fields(1).Value & "');"
```

Comment: so if i need where clause,should i use UPDATE than INSERT??

Comment: It's the other way round. If you wish to update, you may need a where clause; if you wish to insert, you can't have a where clause. It sounds like you should study an SQL tutorial. Lots of these can be found by the searching.